# Azure Site recovery won't install on Stand alone Windows Server 2016 Core - C++ module failed to load

Tags: windows, azure, windows-server-2016

Attempting to install Azure site recovery on Windows Server 2016 hyper-v core and unable to install.  The server is a new installation and has no other applications other than windows server 2016 core and the most recent updates.  Each time attempting to launch the installation from command line running either:

setupdr.exe /i (post extraction of the exe)

or running AzureSiteRecoveryProvider.exe directly

Rebooting did not help.

The following error is received each time and unable to continue with the installation:

SetupDR.exe has stopped working.

```
**    Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception. ---> <CrtImplementationDetails>.ModuleLoadException: The C++ module failed to load during appdomain initialization.
 ---> System.DllNotFoundException: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\WPF\wpfgfx_v0400.dll ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified module could not be found
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MS.Internal.NativeWPFDLLLoader.LoadNativeWPFDLL(UInt16* relDllPath, UInt16* baseDllPath)
   at MS.Internal.NativeWPFDLLLoader.LoadCommonDLLsAndDwrite()
   at CModuleInitialize.{ctor}(CModuleInitialize* , IntPtr cleaningUpFunc)
   at ?A0x3dfe6d80.CreateCModuleInitialize()
   at ?A0x3dfe6d80.??__E?A0x3dfe6d80@cmiStartupRunner@@YMXXZ()
   at _initterm_m((fnptr)* pfbegin, (fnptr)* pfend)
   at <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.InitializePerAppDomain(LanguageSupport* )
   at <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport._Initialize(LanguageSupport* )
   at <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Initialize(LanguageSupport* )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at <CrtImplementationDetails>.ThrowModuleLoadException(String errorMessage, Exception innerException)
   at <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Initialize(LanguageSupport* )
   at .cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.DisasterRecovery.Setup.Program.Main()**
```

Comment: i'm having the same issue. did you get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got past this issue by running windows update. 
I had the same problem and got the same error, but running windows update supplied whatever dependency is missing.

I'm now stuck trying to set the vault credentials on the commandline but I at least got it to install.

Comment: Thanks that did it. I waited long enough and another update came out and it fixed it.  For your problem with the license it's fixed by registering the license via command line using DRConfigurator.exe.  Here is an article that has the command you'll need: http://adinermie.com/using-asr-standalone-hyper-v-host-configured-cluster/

Answer (score 0):

Check if the VC++ is 4.5 and above